# Appcelerator Studio on the Mac "Invalid password" when trying to update

Tags: macos, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

Whenever I try to update Appcelerator studio by going to Help>Check for updates I get stuck at the password entry screen. (Even though I'm using the correct password).

I tried changing the password through the command line and the solutions mentioned here:
https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/145775/mac-os-x-cant-install-titanium-cli--alloy---invalid-password
https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/149303/titanium-studio-is-unable-to-validate-the-provided-system-password

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was actually to change the password through System Preferences>Users & Groups.

I was using my iCloud password as the system password for my Mac so by pressing "Change Password..." and then "Use separate password" to create a password - Appcelerator finally accepted my system authentication.

Comment: This issue is tracked at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7762 and should have been fixed since Studio 4.4.0. If you are using that or a later Studio version, could you please leave a comment on the JIRA ticket to ask it to be reopened?